# Props are undefined until component reloads

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I want to my map through an object's array and create a table like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Scoreboard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">
      <table>
        {props.players.map((val, num) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <tl>{val.id} :</tl>
              <tl>{val.name}</tl>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is that props.players is `undefined` in the first component load.

If I change the code React reloads the component and the table finally appears.

I tried using **useState** and **useEffect** but It didn't work.

EDIT:
I think that maybe the problem is that when the Scoreboard component is generated (and passed the props), the players array has not value in the parent.

Comment: Are you loading the players from an API?

Comment: No, It's an array that I generated in the parent module

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Scoreboard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">
      <table>
        {props?.players?.map((val, num) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <tl>{val.id} :</tl>
              <tl>{val.name}</tl>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that it is undefined, but that the component doesn't reload when it update its value.
I tried useState and useEffect but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have enough information but is `players` a usestate variable in the parent component?

Comment: Nope, it's a normal variable

Comment: so maybe that's why it's not working, useState will render it automatically hop this works for you:)

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition and render the data only if the props.players exists

```
import React from "react";

export default function Scoreboard(props) {
  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">
      <table>
        {props.players && props.players.map((val, num) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <tl>{val.id} :</tl>
              <tl>{val.name}</tl>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do it with the least amount of code would be to give props a default parameter value:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function Scoreboard(props={players:[]}) {
  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">
      <table>
        {props.players.map((val, num) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <tl>{val.id} :</tl>
              <tl>{val.name}</tl>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think this achieve the same results that adding conditionals in your JSX would